# Como adicionar um array dentro de um array de array?

Tags: php, array-multidimensional

```
$regras = array(
    array(
        'field' => 'cpf',
        'label' => 'CPF',
        'rules' => 'required'
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'senha',
        'label' => 'SENHA',
        'rules' => 'required|trim'
));
// o array $maisUmCriterio tem que ser inserido dentro de $regras
$maisUmCriterio =    
    array(
        'field' => 'nome',
        'label' => 'NOME',
        'rules' => 'required|trim'
);

// já tentei fazer

$regras = $regras + $maisUmCriterio;

// mas não funciona, preciso que o array $regras fique assim :

$regras = array(
    array(
        'field' => 'cpf',
        'label' => 'CPF',
        'rules' => 'required'
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'senha',
        'label' => 'SENHA',
        'rules' => 'required|trim'
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'nome',
        'label' => 'NOME',
        'rules' => 'required|trim'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Falta-te uma coisa, que é "[]" no final do nome da variável onde queres inserir o novo array:

Temos:

```
$regras = array(
    array(
        'field' => 'cpf', 
        'label' => 'CPF',
        'rules' => 'required'
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'senha',
        'label' => 'SENHA',
        'rules' => 'required|trim'
    ),
);
```

Para adicionar mais um array dentro desse array:

```
$regras[] = array(
    'field' => 'nome',
    'label' => 'NOME',
    'rules' => 'required|trim'
);
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/8beyB4)

Na realidade até tens mais metodos:

[array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php), adcionas ao princício do array:

```
$add = array(
    'field' => 'nome',
    'label' => 'NOME',
    'rules' => 'required|trim'
);

array_unshift($regras, $add);
```

[array_push](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp), adionas no fim (semelhante ao primeiro exemplo que dei):

```
$add = array(
    'field' => 'nome',
    'label' => 'NOME',
    'rules' => 'required|trim'
);

array_push($regras, $add);
```